# How to make getElementsByClassName do changes to all elements?

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript, I want to apply changes to all the elements with the same class name but I can only get my script to make the changes to the first element.

This is my script. Thanks in advance.

```
function ReadMore(){  
var txt = document.getElementsByClassName('pa')[0].innerHTML;


var btn=document.createElement("BUTTON");
var t=document.createTextNode("...");
btn.appendChild(t);
btn.onclick = function(){
document.getElementsByClassName("pa")[0].innerHTML= txt;
 };

if (txt.length > 350){
var split = txt.slice(0, 50); 
document.getElementsByClassName("pa")[0].innerHTML= split;
document.getElementsByClassName("pa")[0].appendChild(btn);
}}
```

Comment: Use a `for` loop to loop over the elements, then apply the action to each one.  `var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('pa');  for(var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++){ var e = ele[i]; }`.

Comment: You are making elements just to the first element `document.getElementsByClassName('pa')[0].innerHTML` , the zero means : the first element of the array

Comment: please guys, do not use `document.getElementsByClassName('pa')`, it is not a cross-browser function. `document.querySelectorAll('.pa')` does the same in all browsers.

Comment: @MehranHatami: what browser does QSA that doesn't do GEBCN? besides, sometimes you need a htmlcollection instead of just a nodelist.

Comment: @dandavis: just new versions of IE and Opera support GEBCN, since IE has totally moved to Mozilla core and Opera to WebKit. there might be more, not in my mind right now. check this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800914/document-getelementbyclassname-cross-browser-fix) out.

Comment: @MehranHatami: no. both IE and opera have supported it since v9. http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname. also, IE is NOT using any mozilla code; they have a pretty good layout engine of their own... you can write a simple fallback for IE8 if you don't need live collections.

Comment: @dandavis: not **mozilla code**, Mozilla **core**. open an IE and write this down in the developer tools: `navigator.userAgent`, the result: "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0;......", yes as you said IE supported it since v9, when he threw away the whole old kernel and moved to a Mozilla **core**.

Comment: @dandavis: no problem due, use it if you are sure, none of your clients use IE8 or old version of Opera.

Comment: @MehranHatami: i think just about all userAgents contain "Mozilla/5.0", it has nothing to do with the actual browser technology...

Comment: @dandavis: not in IE8 or the older version, BTW, let finish this up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to write your code i only change your code for a loop and i don't know what do you want to  do with your elements but if you want to do it for all items you can use this code

```
function ReadMore(){  

   var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('pa');

   for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {  
       var item = elements[i];    
       var txt = item.innerHTML;
       var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
       var t = document.createTextNode("...");

       btn.appendChild(t);
       btn.onclick = function(){
         item.innerHTML= txt;
       };

       if (txt.length > 350){
           var split = txt.slice(0, 50); 
           item.innerHTML = split;
           item.appendChild(btn);      
       }    
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through them:

```
var collection = document.getElementsByClassName("pa");
for(i=0; i<collection.length; i++){
   collection[i].innerHTML = 'Hello ' + i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, the variable[0] refers to the first item in an array. You are only referencing the first item, so of course you won't be able to handle them all.

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array, so:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('pa'); 

for( var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { 
  var e = elements[i]; 
  e.innerHTML= split;
  e.appendChild(btn);
}
```